# Subquery returns more than 1 row, SQL

Tags: sql

My query returns more than one row:

```
SELECT ar.artistname 
FROM artists ar 
WHERE ar.artistid =
                   (SELECT x.artistid 
                    FROM xrefartistsmembers x);
```

How can I rewrite this to match the `ids` from the two tables? I cannot use a JOIN condition.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL,...)?

Comment: Some information about the schema would be useful. May you should be getting more than one row. And why can't `JOINS` be used?

Answer (score 4):

This will avoid the JOIN, but there's no guarantee it will be faster.

```
SELECT ar.artistname 
FROM artists ar 
WHERE ar.artistid IN
                    (SELECT x.artistid 
                     FROM xrefartistsmembers x);
```